# Is having many thin factories an antipattern?

Tags: design-patterns, anti-patterns

I need to perform the following task: for a user `user@domain.com`, store a blob of data into their dedicated data store.

- `DataStoreService` is what actually stores the blob of data in the user's store, however it needs a `StoreClientFactory` which owns the logic for picking which store belongs to the given user.
- `StoreClientFactory` retrieves the store based on the user's email address, however it needs to inject a credential, which will be different when running locally vs the cloud
- `ICredentialFactory` has several concrete implementations, for example `LocalCredentialFactory`, `CloudCredentialFactory`, which is injected depending on the environment where the app runs.

My service ends up like this:

```cs
public class DataStoreService : IDataStoreService
{
    private IStoreClientFactory StoreClientFactory { get; set; }

    public DataStoreService(IStoreClientFactory storeClientFactory)
    {
        StoreClientFactory = storeClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task StoreBlobAsync(string email, DataBlob blob)
    {
        var storeClient = StoreClientFactory.GetUserStore(email);
        await storeClient.StoreAsync(blob);
    }
}

public class StoreClientFactory : IStoreClientFactory
{
    private ICredentialFactory CredentialFactory { get; set; }

    public StoreClientFactory(ICredentialFactory credentialFactory)
    {
        CredentialFactory = credentialFactory;
    }

    public StoreClient GetUserStore(string email)
    {
        var credential = CredentialFactory.GetCredential();

        var urlForUserStore = StoreUtils.GetUrlForUserStore(email);
        return StoreClient(url, credential);
    }
}

public class LocalCredentialFactory : ICredentialFactory
{
    public ICredential GetCredential()
    {
        return new LocalCredential();
    }
}
```

This could continue with 1-2 more layers. Is this the best solution in my case or can I improve it?

Edit: the code is used in an ASP.NET Core API Controller:

```cs
public class DataStoreController
{
    private DataStoreService DataStoreService { get; set; }

    public DataStoreController(DataStoreService dataStoreService)
    {
        DataStoreService = dataStoreService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(DataBlob blob)
    {
        await DataStoreService.StoreBlobAsync(User.Identity.Name, blob);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code used to construct this.

Comment: @candied_orange With the exception of class / method names, this is the actual code.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you drive this code. Which means it's dead and lifeless. You want to know if this is the "best solution". Give me something to judge. Even a unit test would help.

Comment: @candied_orange Updated with sample controller.

Comment: It's not wrong but you could simplify it. For example, you could provide the credential itself instead of providing the factory as your application will know during startup whether it's local or cloud. There are other ways you can simplify this as well

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks. What other ways?

Comment: Well you should probably get rid of the static utility class and perhaps you could resolve the URL for the user in a request scoped service. Opinions will vary.

Comment: Still don't see construction code. Pity this isn't getting more attention.

Comment: @candied_orange please be clear about what you're looking for exactly and why. The "construction code", ie a bunch of extension methods on IServiceCollection called from Program.cs, which is standard ASP.NET Core) will make no difference to the fundamental question of having these thin interfaces.

Comment: @async the point of factories is to build objects. Yet you wont show us the building of these objects. Makes it hard to tell if the factories are doing anything useful.